# Sequence on a created table in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking to implement a sequence on the ID field in the tables which I have already created, in SQL Server 2012.

There are 4 such tables, all have their respective ID fields.

Could you please help me out with the appropriate instructions? For instance, I have a table Medicine with the fields(mID, drug) and I would like to create the sequence on the mID field, such that it goes 3000, 3010, 3020 and so on.

Thank You so much.

Comment: Tell us if it worked...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your table's schema looks something like

```
CREATE TABLE medicine (mid INT, drug VARCHAR(255));
```

and you really want to use a sequence you can do

```
CREATE SEQUENCE medicine_seq START WITH 3000 INCREMENT BY 10;
ALTER TABLE medicine ADD DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR medicine_seq) FOR mid;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/823c7/1)** demo

Comment: Hello, first up- thank you to @peterm, everyone who helped me with this question. And I apologize for the delay in response.

But the problem is that neither of the two suggested type of solutions have worked out.

1. For the approach which uses
    create sequence [dbo].[medicineseq] as int
I get the error -Unknown object type sequence used in create, drop or alter statement. 

2. For the approach
    CREATE SEQUENCE Medicine_seq_mID START WITH 3000 INCREMENT BY 10;

I get the error- incorrect syntax near sequence(same error for NEXT and 3000)

Please provide your suggestions here, thank you.

Comment: Did you take a look at working sqlfiddle demo provided? If you get syntax errors you either using a version of SQL Server prior to 2012 or doing something wrong, at least not as suggested in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to use the object explorer to modify the mid column? first step is to create the sequence object use object explore, you can locate the sequence under programmability in the corresponding database, right click "sequence", select "new sequence", give the sequence a proper name as "dbo.sequence_mid", set the seed and increment perspectively “3000” and "10", click ok to complete the sequence creation. Start a new query window, insert into  values (next value for [dbo].[Sequence_mid], , )